# How to iterate over an array and store into a new array by keyword

Tags: arrays, ruby, oop, web-scraping, nokogiri

I currently have a method that scrapes data from a website and stores that info in an array to later be randomly called on by its index(random to the user). I was thinking to take it a step further and iterate over this array and create new arrays where the data is stored by specific keywords where a user can specify if they want a fact about trees, flowers, or food.

How can I code this? do I need to create a new class? or method? do I need to define the array name to be called upon in another method to iterate over again? what is an efficent way to do this.

my current scraper stored in an array is

```
def facts 
array=[]

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open("https://www.funfactsabout.net/plant-facts/"))
doc.css("ul.facts-list li").each do |list|
array.push(list.text)
end
return array
end
```

and then one of the methods I have in my class is

```
def more
    input_prompt = "\n\n Enter a number between 1-42 for a random plant fact, or type 'leave' to exit: \n\n"
input = nil
    while true
      puts input_prompt
      input = gets.strip
      if input.to_i > 0 && input.to_i < facts.length + 1
       puts facts[input.to_i - 1]
      elsif input == "leave"
        puts goodbye
        return
      else
        puts "Sorry, I didn't understand that." 
   

     end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a class for this, something like

```
class RandomFacts
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def to_a 
    document.css("ul.facts-list li").map do |list|
      list.text
    end
  end

  private

  def document
    Nokogiri::HTML(url)
  end

  def url
    URI.open("https://www.funfactsabout.net/#{name}-facts/")
  end
end
```

In the class you construct the URL based on the fact name like this

```rb
RandomFacts.new("plant").to_a
RandomFacts.new("science").to_a
```

And then you have to prompt the user on the fact and the number and can generate e.g. like a hash

```rb
facts = {
  "science" => RandomFacts.new("science").to_a,
  "plant" => RandomFacts.new("plant").to_a
}

facts["plant"][1]
facts["science"][42]
```

Comment: Looking at the usage of the class, then `name` attr_reader could also be private.

Comment: Yeah could be private although it makes sense to expose the name of the facts in my opinion.

Comment: FYI, the `map` in your `to_a` method would more idiomatically be written `document.css("ul.facts-list li").map(&:text)`.

Comment: Nice. One extra - `to_a` should probably be memoized

Comment: Yeah could be memoized although if you store it in a hash it should be fine doesn't necessarily need to memoized twice.